# Determine user type in Google Class Room (Either Teacher or Student)

Tags: javascript, api, meteor, roles, google-classroom

How can I determine if a user that is logged into my app is a Teacher or a Student?

I can successfully log in to my app using a Google Classroom test account, but when I look at the information retrieved, I see nothing in regards to role. I've looked through the API but so far I've only seen calls related to getting courses and rosters. I tried the user profile call, but the info returned did not include a role.

At a basic level, I just want to do `loggedInUser.role === teacher`.

Edit:
Updated for clarification. I am not looking for courses.students or courses.teachers. I consider those roster information. I already have a profile from a logged in user. I shouldn't have to see what role they are by listing teachers in a course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the Classroom API, you can only determine if a user is a teacher or a student **relative to a particular course**. (It's possible for a user to be a teacher in one course, and a student in another.)

If you need to determine if a user is a real-world teacher or student, you need to do this via a mechanism separate from Classroom.

You might also like to [star this issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4236) to learn about any possible improvements to the API.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for courses.students and courses.teachers:

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.teachers

Once you have a course ID you can query these using the "list" request:

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.teachers/list
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list

Comment: Updated my question to clarify why this doesn't answer my question. Thank you for the effort though

Comment: You'll still need to go through with it. Aside from the 2 methods specified by @stephen-woods, there are `invitations` and `userProfiles` methods which don't have `roles` like you're asking.